# Determining when an app finished sending a file with ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, file, send

In my app I'm sending files opening external apps (Dropbox, email, etc...) using ACTION_SEND. I would like to know when the external app has finished sending the file. Maybe can I detect if the file is being read by another app?

Answer (score 0):

try to use *onActivityResult*

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SEND_THE_FILE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // file used by another app.
        } else {
            // sending failed/cancelled
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It will be fired when the user go back to my app. Imagine that you share a file with Dropbox: I would like to know when Dropbox finished uploading the file.